# Eigenvalues of an induced subgraph of a random graph

Tags: adjacency-matrix, random-graphs

Suppose $G$ is a random graph on $n$ vertices where each edge appears with probability half. Suppose someone looks at the resulting graph and chooses an arbitrary subset $W$ of vertices of size $k>\sqrt{n}$.  How do the eigenvalues of the induced subgraph $G[W]$ behave?
In other words can we say that for every $W$ of size $k$, the eigenvalues of $G[W]$ will be close or related to that of a random graph from $G(k,1/2)$?

Comment: Are the edges in $G$ independently chosen? If so, I don't know how $G[W]$ is different from $G(k,1/2)$.

Comment: @WillardZhan, yes.  It's different because $W$ might be a function of $G$, e.g., $W=f(G)$.  i.e., imagine an adversary who sees the chosen graph $G$, then tries to choose a vertex set $W$ so that $G[W]$ has unusual eigenvalues.  Can the adversary do that?  It's not clear.  I can certainly arrange that $G[W]$ doesn't follow a $G(k,1/2)$ distribution: e.g., find any triangle in $G$, and let $W$ be those three vertices; then $G[W]$ is always a triangle (probability 1), but $G(k,1/2)$ would be a triangle with probability just $1/8$.